# Using enumitem & setlist, itemsep doesn't work with pandoc

Tags: enumitem, pandoc

I'm using the `enumitem` package with a `setlist` `header-include` to customize definition lists, and it's working great, *except* that no matter what value I give to `itemsep` the vertical space between items remains unaffected. Similarly, `parsep` does not work. The other options in my `setlist` work as expected (`leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries99}, font=\normalfont`). I'm writing in markdown and using YAML metadata and Pandoc to generate a PDF. Here is my metadata, followed by the Pandoc command I've been using:

**[UPDATED EXAMPLE]**

```
---
title: |
    | The Title of This Document Is Itself the Title
author: Me Myself
documentclass: apa7
classoption:
- doc
- donotrepeattitle
- 12pt
header-includes:
   - \affiliation{Lorem Ipsum Institute}
   - \shorttitle{shortish title}
   - \raggedright
   - \righthyphenmin=62
   - \lefthyphenmin=62
   - \usepackage{hanging}
   - \usepackage{setspace}
   - \setstretch{1.25}
   - \usepackage{enumitem}
   - \setlist[description]{itemsep=1in, leftmargin=15pt, labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries99}, font=\normalfont}
   - \newfontfamily\GreekToMe[Scale=MatchLowercase]{EB Garamond}
   - \renewcommand{\abstractname}{   }
   - \abstract{\singlespacing\small{Lorem ipsum…}}
...

Here’s some text. I’m writing entirely in markdown. I am using a definition list as a way to align a bit of dialogue, like so:

A:
: Person A speaks to Person B, and drones on and on and on, just to illustrate why I’m using definition lists. When I used the package hanging, I lost my markdown formatting in the dialogue; e.g. the word “space” in the next line appeared in the PDF as \*space\* instead of *space*. Using the definition list, I get my hanging indent and keep my markdown formatting.

B:
: Person B says, Can I please have some *space*, man?

A:
: Person A says, No can do—even though `itemsep=1in`!
```

Pandoc command:

```
$ pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex input.md -o output.pdf
```

And here is the resulting PDF:
[image: output.pdf]

I'm new to using LaTeX and Pandoc and YAML, and I won't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious. But it does seem weird that most options in the `setlist` are working and the vertical space ones are not.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can simplify your example and make it compilable? And show how you're actually entering the lists in the .md file. Are they raw LaTeX (`\begin{description} \item[ ] ... \end{description}` or Markdown?

Comment: I've updated the example. I compiled it with the Pandoc command shown, and the result was the same: itemsep has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons that I don't understand, `pandoc` makes extensive use of the macro `\tightlist` which it seems to insert in every list it generates. The `tightlist` macro sets the list `\itemsep` and `\parsep` to `0pt` which is why your changes using `enumitem` are being overridden. The simplest way to solve this is to simply add the line

```
   - \let\tightlist\relax
```

to your `header-includes` block.  This will make `\tightlist` do nothing, and the settings you set with `enumitem` will be respected.

Unrelated, but the `\affiliation` macro is deprecated in the `apa7` class. You're apparently supposed to use `\authorsaffiliations` according to the warning text.

To debug this sort of problem in the future, it can be helpful to have `pandoc` generate the `.tex` file instead of the `.pdf` so that you can inspect its code directly. Of course if you're new to LaTeX this might not be so helpful, but if you become more familiar with it, it will probably be a useful tool for debugging.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. If I did want to look at the LateX code directly, what program would you recommend that would show the code big & clearly? I downloaded TexMaker the other day, and the output code was tiny and cramped.

Comment: In fact, now that `tightlist` is relaxed, I need to set `itemsep` to a low negative value to get the spacing I want.

Comment: I use TeXShop which is a mature native IDE. I’m not sure you should be setting `itemsep` to a negative value.

Comment: I will check out TeXShop, thank you. Are there negative consequences to setting `itemsep` to a negative number, or a better way to accomplish narrowing vertical spacing in the list, or just bad karma?…

Comment: Not necessarily bad, but it's likely there's a more sensible way to achieve what you want. :)